# Need to Extract Product Cost (Not Price) From OpenCart Database

Tags: database, opencart, opencart2.x

I migrated my Opencart site to Wordpress but unfortunately couldn't transfer the product cost as there is no cost field in Woocommerce. I later installed woocommerce cost plugin and realised I never transferred the cost from OpenCart. All I am left with is the old OpenCart DB. How can I get the Product cost from the SQL File ? I can do it manually if I know which table has the costs.

Answer (score 0):

in OC database `oc_product`(if you not changed `oc_` prefix) table has product cost. Column with name `price` there the price without taxes. IN OC no additional cost's of the products. Additional prices (cost) calculating during the purchase and storing to the database tables with name `oc_order_product` and `oc_order_total`.

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce have 2 price for product: get_price,get_regular_price ;

OpenCart system have little different discount. Its using tables

- oc_product  - main price
- oc_product_discount  - event price
- oc_product_special - event price

You can get it by queries:

```
(SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_discount pd2 
    WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id 
    AND pd2.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_customer_group_id') . "' 
    AND pd2.quantity = '1' 
    AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()) 
    AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())) 
ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS discount, 

(SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps 
    WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id 
    AND ps.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_customer_group_id') . "' 
    AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) 
    AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) 
ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special,
```